# Unable to delete records from table due to constraints in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am receiving this error when I try to delete a record from assessment table.

```
 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`assessment`.`assessment_answer`, CONSTRAINT `consAssessmentId` FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_id`) REFERENCES `assessment` (`id`)). The SQL statement executed was: DELETE FROM `assessment` WHERE created_by=14
```

I have to delete user's all data, including record from these tables: users, assessment, assessment answer.

I can delete user record easily but having above error while remove assessment table record. After assessment table, I need to delete users record from assessment answer table as well.

Can you please help me fix this?

I have 3 tables: assessment answer

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assessment_answer` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `assessment_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_value` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `question_id` (`question_id`),
  KEY `assessment_id` (`assessment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=200 ;
```

assessment table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assessment` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `created_by_2` (`created_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

and user table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0: Inactive, 1: Active, 2: Deleted',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

And if I take SQL dump I get this,

```
--
-- Constraints for table `assessment_answer`
--
ALTER TABLE `assessment_answer`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `consAssessmentId` FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_id`) REFERENCES `assessment` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `consQuestionId` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `assessment` is parent, and `assessment_answer` is child. 1 parent may have many children. 1 child has only 1 parent.

Suppose you could delete a record id 100 from `assessment` table successfully, then all the records in `assessment_answer` table having `assessment_id` of 100 will become invalid (assessment record id 100 has already gone!). Data integrity is broken.

There are 2 solutions:

1) Manually, `assessment_answer` records must be deleted first, then you can delete `assessment` record. In other words, delete child records associated with a parent first, then delete the parent.

```
DELETE FROM assessment_answer WHERE assessment_id = 100
DELETE FROM assessment WHERE id = 100
```

2) Technically, you can let Mysql to handle the task by declaring `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign constraint for the parent-child relationship

```
ALTER TABLE `assessment_answer`
ADD CONSTRAINT `consAssessmentId` FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_id`) REFERENCES `assessment` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

It tells Mysql to **always** delete child data when parent data is deleted. Then, you execute one SQL command only to delete relating records in both tables

```
DELETE FROM assessment WHERE created_by = 14
```

Comment: Thanks Rocherlee. I am not able to update the constraint to add "on delete cascade" but alternately able to delete all assessment answer record and assessment records now.